# Images are being repeated in ngfor

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an issue where I have all the images being repeated for each button item. I need a single image being displayed for each item instead of all of them. Thank you. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let c of weapons?.weapon_category?.weapons | search : terms">

  <button ion-item (click)="presentPopover($event,c)">
       <img *ngFor="let v of weapons?.url_category?.url_weapon" src="/assets/weapon/{{v.name}}"/>
       <h2>{{c.name}}</h2>
  </button>
</ion-item>
```

**After**
I have applied the changes. However, the images are no longer being displayed for some reason.

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let c of weapons?.weapon_category?.weapons | search : terms">
  <button  ion-item (click)="presentPopover($event,c)">
       <img src="/assets/weapon/{{c.url_category?.url_weapon?.name}}"/>
       <h2>{{c.name}}</h2>
  </button>
</ion-item>
```

**Json Object**

```
{
  "categories": {

    "weapon_category": {

      "weapons": [
        {
          "name": "AKM",
        }
      ]},
     "url_category": {

      "url_weapon": [{
            "type": "file",
            "name": "Icon_weapon_AKM.png"
        }
       ]}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to be a naming issue: you're using `weapons` twice, but it seems like you want to be using `c` for lookupsin the loop.

Try this:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let c of weapons?.weapon_category?.weapons | search : terms">
  <button ion-item (click)="presentPopover($event,c)">
       <img src="/assets/weapon/{{c.url_category.url_weapon}}"/>
       <h2>{{c.name}}</h2>
  </button>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Seems like your solution should work. However, the images are now no longer showing.

Comment: Perhaps try adding the elvis operator back in -- `c?.url_category?.url_weapon`

Comment: It could also be that I did not guess the correct shape of your JSON -- update your answer with the shape of your object and I will take a look.

Comment: I have tried adding the operator back in. However, I am still getting a 404 response.

Comment: Based on your JSON object, it is just a problem with your data structure. If every weapon should have one image, then you need to associate an image with each weapon. Right now, weapons only have a "name" and there is no clear way to tie the objects in the `url_category` object to items in the `weapons_category` object. If I were you, I'd just add a `url` property to each `weapon` with its image url.

Comment: I have considered this. However, this would require me to manually do this for hundreds of weapons or to write some script to join the two. Do you have any recommendations as this would be time intensive to do it manually.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have figured out how to join the url category into weapons category.

Comment: Nice! Happy to help :)

Comment: Would you consider up-voting my question? It appears I have been question banned until my score is improved.

Comment: It's showing up fine to me -- what do you mean question banned?

Comment: The stack overflow algorithm found me to be unworthy of asking any more questions. "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account". I read that getting more up-votes on my previous questions will help me get unbanned. Hope you understand.